# How to override the stylesheets embedded in the Telerik assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

Embedding RadEditor in my page but Master page's CSS is screwing it up ..like Editor's content area is inheriting background-image property of the body tag when I want it to be white..drop down lists inside of Editor too are not displaying correctly..I don't wanna create whole new custom skin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable all styles on an element ? Any property to set all attributes of an element to none all in one go? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051442/how-do-you-disable-all-styles-on-an-element-any-property-to-set-all-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each stylesheet is sent to the browser as separate file you can use HttpHandler, check the file path and if it's Telerik style sheet, change the contents on the fly.