# How do you disable all styles on an element ? Any property to set all attributes of an element to none all in one go?

Tags: css

I am embedding telerik's radEditor in my page..its inheriting css properties from the master page..like H2 is in blue color..its got background color...

what should I type in my custom css class (the one exclusively made for radEditor) so it over rides ALL the Master page's css properties and applies nothing to heading tags??

I wrote this:-

```
h2{color:black;background-image:none;}
```

still h2 tag doesn't appear smaller that H1 tag in the drop down list in my radEditor..it still is applying css from master page..do I need to search for ALL the attributes being applied in master page and set them to none one by one in my custom css file ?/

Comment: this is a dirty hack but why not rename the tag `<style>` to something like `<whoops>`, could result in some weird behavior, but I doubt the browser would keep interpreting that style code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no such possibility in CSS. You have two options:

1: Select your H2 elements as specifically as possible and then apply your css to remove the styling. Pseudo code, as I do not know the structure of your HTML:

```
#master_page #page h2{font-style:none; etc...}
```

2: Use JavaScript to dynamically remove all formatting of a selected element. This solution however implies you could not restyle the element at all, so I guess it's not what you're looking for. just to be complete :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `!important` keyword in your styles to override any previously applied styles something like this:

```
h2{
   color:black !important;
   background-image:none  !important;
}
```

Having said that, it is generally *not recommended* because it might create problems for others applying the styles unless they figure out that `! important` is being used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shorthand command for reset in CSS. You'd have to override every CSS property explicitly.

Comment: oh but there are like 10 properties in master page's css ! right from font size, color, margin to padding and what not :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and Azeo's #2 worked for me:

```
 function RadEditorLoad(editor, eventArgs) {

        // Set these Editor Styles to prevent them from being inherited
        // from the master page.  
        editor.get_contentArea().style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
        editor.get_contentArea().style.backgroundColor = 'White';
        editor.get_contentArea().style.textAlign = 'Left';
        editor.get_contentArea().style.padding = "5px";
    } 


  <telerik:RadEditor ...         OnClientLoad="RadEditorLoad">
```

**Update:**
I ended up using the ContentAreaCssFile Property in favor of the solution above.  As described in:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/settingcontentareadefaults/defaultcs.aspx.
I'm only able to reset specific styles that are important to me, not all styles unfortunately.