# Reset element with a rule (delete all element styles on one class)

Tags: css

I was wondering, is there any CSS rule to reset an element style?

It would be great to be able to use just with one class like `.reset`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying really hard to think of a reason you'd need this in straight CSS to be honest. I could see a jQuery application for wanting to remove styles but that's relatively easy anyway. If you don't want something to have any styles just don't give it one.

Comment: in my case will be useful using bootstrap, don't know about you sorry.

Comment: Are you building your CSS from .Less? It may be easier to isolate and modify/override this way.

Comment: nope, i just extend bootstrap.css with extra rules in new css file :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable all styles on an element ? Any property to set all attributes of an element to none all in one go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051442/how-do-you-disable-all-styles-on-an-element-any-property-to-set-all-attributes)

Comment: anyway do not turn the discussion on bootstrap :P i asked if is possible with a simple css rule if is not please answer NOT IS NOT POSSIBLE :)

Comment: Let's put it another way. The only reason you would need a reset code is if you're using CSS 'wrong'. In other words: targeting the wrong (or too many) elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single CSS class that will "reset" styles to whatever you want:

```
.reset{
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-weight:normal;
  /*etc.*/
}
```

Then apply to your elements:

```
<h1 class="reset">...</h1>
```

Is this what you are after?

Just keep in mind that the first "C" in CSS stands for Cascading and thus you may need to be more specific in the CSS to overcome other styles applied to an element. [CSS Precedence reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

Comment: Actually, depending on the selectors strength (e.a. #item .item) this would not work most of the time. !important would be required.

Comment: I don't think there are any tricks. Cascading styles from one element to the other is the whole point of CSS (as Scunliffe mentioned).

Comment: @Damien correct... I was adding a link to the CSS specs for dealing with the selector strength/precedence likely while you added your comment.