# Is there a way to have an Element opt out of the CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a general CSS that has loads of stylesheets. I want to use jQuery to tell a table I have to ignore the "all.css" rules and just do its own thing. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051442/how-do-you-disable-all-styles-on-an-element-any-property-to-set-all-attributes

Comment: @CarlosViniciusVieiraRodrigu those answers are old. There are new possiblities

Comment: @Harsh IE9 and over though, which might be a problem. (It seems like IE8 is the new IE6 :/)

Comment: If you *don't* want to have to scope all your main CSS under a `:not()` selector, you could also take the brute force approach and include a browser's stylesheet under the table's selector to reset everything to the defaults. (That said, this is a very clunky approach and namespacing your site-wide styles if you need them to not apply to something would be better.)

Comment: frankly, people should give up XP now. XP users can't get beyond IE8. I know it's gonna be a slow transition and may make IE8 the new IE6, but things are still way better than those IE6 days... Hope IE10 catches up soon

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use an `id` which overrides general css selectors and fill in all default styles.

```
#table {
    //default styles
}
```

Comment: -1 for mis-using important. If you're doing it right, the css for that id should be more specific anyway as the OP surely targets the general table tag, which has lower precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :not selector, which is now a CSS3 standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Use it like this:

```
table:not(.old-style) {
    width: 666%;
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Of course, don't use those values :P

Comment: Keep in mind that older browsers will not support this. You only need to worry about this if supporting out-of-date browsers is an explicit requirement. You can find a list of supported browsers here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: i answered the same thing before SO went oups! . There's polyfill or even jQuery that mimic this selector.

Answer (score 0):

Why rewrite or overwrite rules when CSS/jQuery can do it simple.

```
    table:not([id="excludeThisTable"]) 
{
   /* style for any table exept #excludeThisTable */
}
```

jQuery manage this selector i believe. http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ or http://api.jquery.com/not/

My choice would go for CSS + polyfill :(shorter in time  than with jQuery) 
update selector in CSS, add polyfill for olderbrowser and keep going on with the rest

Comment: I believe the jQuery selector extensions are just for use within jQuery DOM queries. It sounds like the question author is trying to exclude a DOM node from receiving CSS styles rather than excluding it from a jQuery query.

Comment: @Corion It's a CSS selector as well. Although the syntax might be a little different.

Comment: @millimoose But jQuery doesn't add suppot for it in CSS 2.1 does it? This answer makes it sound like it does.

Comment: Did I missunderstood the question ?. I propose here to exclude one peticular table from being styled , via CSS, or via jQuery . There is polyfills to get this selector working for older browser . The one thing to do is to use the selector :not() it can be from any attributes .

Comment: @Corion The question says "I want to use jQuery", and you can certainly use that library to selectively apply styling. (The question is not exactly fortunately phrased though, and it's true that this is doable without jQuery with `:not()` support.)

Comment: What I was trying to clarify was that to my knowledge, jQuery by itself does not make CSS2.1 browsers suddenly parse CSS3 files correctly. To use `:not()` it in CSS files viewed with CSS2.1 browsers, you need something like [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) in addition to jQuery. If you used JavaScript with jQuery you could still select such an element, but the code sample for this answer is CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: the answers says that CSS does it and that jQuery too . So he has choices : 1) add the selector in css file and keep going 2) add selector in CSS + polyfill 3) use jQuery and polyfill if needed. From these , he can make his choice. Anyhow, to me CSS + polyfill will be the most efficient, no need to rewrite or overwrite the styles via JS.

Comment: Hey guys, i do not have access to the css file and it is styling a table i'm using that i do not want it to style. That is why i'm trying to "opt-out" my table from the forced styles and add my own class to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would correct your CSS by either telling the styles to not apply to your table (:not operator), or forcing the styles to apply to only elements you want (Not all tables, but perhaps to tables with a class).

This works, but it's nasty:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            }
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i=0;i<style.length;i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            }
            return returns;
        }
        if(dom.currentStyle){
            style = dom.currentStyle;
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            }
            return returns;
        }
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Disable stylesheets
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').prop('disabled', true);
    // Get current styles
    var style=$('#mytable').getStyleObject();
    // Enable stylesheets
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').prop('disabled',false);
    // Apply saved styles
    $('#mytable').css(style);
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMcyT/

It's attaching the bootstrap css to the fiddle.  The code basically disables all the stylesheets on the page, gets the current style of the table, re-enables the stylesheets, then applies all the saved styles to the table as inline styles.

Comment: not quite sure what's going on here.... i do not have access to the css file and it is styling a table i'm using that i do not want it to style. That is why i'm trying to "opt-out" my table from the forced styles and add my own class to it. Hope that clears it up a little.

Comment: You could put an ID on the table and apply the styles that way or via `table#mytable {styles here}` which will likely override the styles from the other stylesheet.  Using the debug feature of your browser should be able to tell you what selector they are using to target your table, and just use either the same selector after they do, or a more specific selector.